# .zshrc is not loaded in standard zsh shell

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Hi I'm new to zsh and was following the https://www.codementor.io/linux/tutorial/configure-linux-toolset-zsh-tmux-vim tutorial. I'm attempting to modify the .zshrc to set the theme, but the zsh doesn't change at all when I close and reopen. The .zshrc is set within /home/usr (my $HOME directory) and $ZDOTDIR is not set. "source .zshrc" also does nothing. Is there anything I'm missing on why my .zshrc is being ignored?

Comment: Are you using Zsh (what’s the output of `echo $SHELL`)?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are in your home directory "source .zshrc" won't work but "source ~/.zshrc" will. To fix the problem of .zshrc not running automatically: Terminal Preferences... Profiles Shell Startup. Then select Run command -zsh.